# mysql update values that end with with another ending

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table with results like this:

```
0001400OL
0578400OL
354085OL
48679OL
```

and if I wanted to replace last characters that end with `400OL` to `ABC`.
How would i do that?

this is the select statement that I have, to show all values that end with `400OL` probably no use to anyone:

```
select pcode from innerb where pcode like '%400OL';
```

this is an expected output:

```
0001ABC
0578ABC
354085OL
48679OL
```

Comment: Consider if there's an opportunity here to improve the design of your table

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [REPLACE](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php) function, then you should do something like that:

```
SELECT REPLACE(pcode, '400OL', 'ABC') FROM innerb WHERE pcode like '%400OL';
```

For instance, if you want to update these values that matched on your `WHERE` clause, run the next statement:

```
UPDATE innerb 
SET pcode = REPLACE(pcode, '400OL', 'ABC') 
WHERE pcode like '%400OL';
```

Comment: but how would i update the whole table? But that is actually what I want, just need to update the table based on the code you have given me. Thanks alot

Comment: You just need to add the UPDATE statement. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks Garcia, appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `REPLACE()`!  Instead:

```
UPDATE innerb
    SET pcode = CONCAT(LEFT(pcode, LENGTH(pcode) - 5), 'ABC')
    WHERE pcode LIKE '%400OL';
```

The problem with `REPLACE()` is that it replaces *all* occurrences of the searched-for string.  You want to only replace the last one, so only change that one.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will do it:

```
UPDATE innerb
SET pcode = REPLACE(pcode, '400OL', 'ABC')
WHERE pcode LIKE '%400OL';
```